# Can Azure Monitor scrape endpoints of apps running at other providers than Azure?

Tags: azure, prometheus, endpoint, spring-actuator, azure-monitor

I am new to Azure and Azure Monitor.

Can Azure Monitor scrape endpoints of apps running at other providers than Azure?

The endpoints are Springboot actuator/prometheus endpoints of several installations/applications installed outside of the Azure world e.g. on Linux virtual maschines (VMWare) .

I googled but didn't find an approach how to include metrics provided by  external (none) Azure installations.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure Arc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/overview) management service  to monitor the Linux or windows machines which were out of azure.

Currently Azure Monitor  Supports the [below languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-monitor/app/platforms) to collect the logs

- C#|VB(.NET)
- Java
- JavaScript
- NodeJS
- Python

Comment: What about metrics (e.g. Spring Actuator Prometheus endpoints) Das Azure Arc also allow scrap the metrics from e.g. ...../acutator/prometheus?